# Add total Int value with toggle button, SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

For the app I'm making I want to mark movies as watched. In the detailView I have a button that toggles between 'watch' and 'watched'. If toggled it should subtract or add, depending on the toggle. Then in the accountView I have a total count of movies seen. All movies that are set as 'watched' should be added up in this total count, but for some reason it is not linked.

Here is the userDefaults code:

```
extension UserDefaults: ObservableObject {

enum UserDefaultsKeys: String, CaseIterable, Identifiable {
    var id: String { rawValue }
    
    case watchedState
    case watchedCount
}

//MARK: - Watched

func setWatchedState(value: Bool, forMovieId movieId: Int) {
    set(value, forKey: "\(UserDefaultsKeys.watchedState.rawValue)_\(movieId)")
}

func getWatchedState(forMovieId movieId: Int) -> Bool {
    return bool(forKey: "\(UserDefaultsKeys.watchedState.rawValue)_\(movieId)")
}

//MARK: - Movie Count

func setWatchedMovieCount(value: Bool, forMovieId movieId: Int) {
    let watchedStateKey = "\(UserDefaultsKeys.watchedState.rawValue)_\(movieId)"
    let currentWatchedState = bool(forKey: watchedStateKey)
    
    // Check if the watched state is changing
    if currentWatchedState != value {
        set(value, forKey: watchedStateKey)
        
        // Update the movie count based on the new watched state
        let watchedCountKey = UserDefaultsKeys.watchedCount.rawValue
        var count = integer(forKey: watchedCountKey)
        
        if value {
            count += 1
        } else {
            count -= 1
        }
        
        set(count, forKey: watchedCountKey)
    }
}

func getWatchedMovieCount() -> Int {
    return integer(forKey: UserDefaultsKeys.watchedCount.rawValue)
}
```

}

The DetailView code

```
struct MovieDetailView: View {

struct CustomColor {
    static let locked = Color("locked")
}

let movie: Movie
@State private var selectedTrailer: MovieVideo?
let imageLoader = ImageLoader()

let username: String
@State var isLoggedIn: Bool

@State private var selectedScore: Int = 1
@State private var watchedOn = false
@State private var savedOn = false
@State private var isMovieSaved: Bool = false

var body: some View {
    (...)
                
                Button(action: {
                    // Watch button
                    if UserDefaults.standard.getLoggedIn() {
                        if watchedOn {
                            UserDefaults.standard.setWatchedMovieCount(value: false, forMovieId: movie.id)
                        } else {
                            UserDefaults.standard.setWatchedMovieCount(value: true, forMovieId: movie.id)
                        }
                        watchedOn.toggle()
                    }
                }) {
                    VStack {
                        if !UserDefaults.standard.getLoggedIn() {
                            Image("Watch (locked)")
                            Text("watch").foregroundColor(CustomColor.locked)
                        } else if watchedOn {
                            Image("Watched")
                            Text("watched")
                        } else {
                            Image("Watch")
                            Text("watch")
                        }
                    }
                }
                .onAppear {
                    watchedOn = UserDefaults.standard.getWatchedState(forMovieId: movie.id)
                }
                .disabled(!UserDefaults.standard.getLoggedIn())
                
                (...)
```

The AccountView code

```
struct AccountView: View {
let username: String
@State private var isLoggedIn = true

@State private var savedMovies: [Movie] = []
@State private var watchedMovies: [Movie] = []

@State private var isMovieSaved: Bool = false

let movie: Movie
var movieListState = MovieListState()

var body: some View {
            
            (...)
            Section {
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    VStack {
                        Text("\(UserDefaults.standard.getWatchedMovieCount())")
                            .font(.system(size: 42, weight: .semibold))
                        Text("Movies Seen")
                            .font(.system(size: 14))
                        Text("0 min")
                            .font(.system(size: 14))
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
            .padding(.vertical)
            
            (...)
```

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Are you presenting the detailView? If so the presenter view won't redraw its views, cause technically it never disappeared.

Comment: No the detailView and AccountView are two separate pages.

Comment: Use `@AppStorage`, `UserDefaults` isn't capable of redrawing on its own

Comment: I think your core issue is detailView not redrawing its views when shown after updates of data on another screen. This is caused by many reason, I suggest reading through this blog. I used this when I had a similar issue and found a fix. Hope this helps. https://www.donnywals.com/understanding-how-and-when-swiftui-decides-to-redraw-views/